# Why Oracle is giving error : "no more tables permitted in this cluster"?

Tags: oracle, clustered-index

I am getting error "no more tables permitted in this cluster" when trying to create a clustered table.

Oracle's [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_5001.htm) about the cluster feature says:

> A cluster can contain a maximum of 32 tables.

But at the time of the error, the cluster contains only 18 tables as per following query:

```
select * from user_tables where cluster_name='MY_CLUSTER';
```

I suspect that the tables that were once part of the cluster but were later dropped are still being counted towards that maximum allowed limit.

Is there a way to check the above hypothesis?

Comment: Drop the cluster and all tables in it, then re-create the cluster and put back the tables you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the view `USER_CLU_COLUMNS`. If you've dropped a table it may still be listed here but with an internal name not its original.

```
select count(distinct (TABLE_NAME))
  from USER_CLU_COLUMNS
 where CLUSTER_NAME = 'MY_CLUSTER';
```

This may be because your database has a recycle bin. Check this:

```
select *
  from RECYCLEBIN
 where ORIGINAL_NAME = '<your table>';
```

Check this [link](http://www.orafaq.com/node/968) out for more information on the recycle bin.

Comment: You are right the USER_CLU_COLUMNS have columns from tables like `BIN$ubP3IsKPTP+Bm+JdVRia4A==$0`

Comment: Using `drop table table_name purge;` seems to fix the problem